# Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

This is not a duplicate, i have dont hours of research on this and tried everything, none of the threads and answers i have found are for VS2017 either

A designer error

I am using VS2017, the project template im using is a winforms control library

Output:

```
    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.Utilities.Exceptions.ThrowEFail()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.CodeModel.CodeTypeRef.LookupTypeSymbol()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.CodeModel.CodeTypeRef.get_TypeKind()
at EnvDTE.CodeTypeRef.get_TypeKind()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomParser.GetUrtTypeFromVsType(CodeTypeRef vsType)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomParser.OnTypePopulateMembers(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration.get_Members()
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)
```

Things i have tried
-Locating the project and item templates and removing them
-Locating the project and item templates cache and removing them
-Resetting all settings to default
-Removing all references to external libraries and controls
-Updating VS
-Plus more i have forgot

The error only occurs in my current project thats quite large, the error only occurs is VS designer, ive also noticed when i build the project, the custom controls dont get updated in designer view, even if i make changes to any of my classes, no changes occur until the project is run

ANY help would be appreciated

Comment: Looks like a corrupted designer file. If you have your project under version control, I'd start looking back for changes in the files.

Comment: @Iain Ballard i will give it a shot, seems its a common error but all the common solutions havent worked for me, i have narrowed it down to a problem with the project but where? i have no idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to create a new project and add all my classes to the project, upon building i got an error that did not appear before, "Could not convert size to bool", this was thrown by creating a new bitmap

```
Bitmap _bg = new Bitmap(BackgroundImage, new Size(Width, Height));
```

I have no idea why it would let me build the previous project but i just decided to create a new Bitmap(Width, Height) and use the graphics to draw the image.

Seems like this may have been the cause of the error